# how to implement opengl es 2.0 2D scene zOrdering?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to render a 2D scene using opengl es 2.0. In this scene i want to have a set of sprites (quads) to be rendered. I'm using orthographic projection. I want each sprite to have some z-value which will determine if it appears on front or back. But I want to render sprites not in z-value order. So how can I still achieve z-ordering is kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that you render using an ortographic projection, the 3rd dimension is still there. Just make sure that the nearz and farz values contain your objects, and remember to enable depth testing. Then you substitute all your 2D coordinates with appropriate 3D coordinates.

Comment: I want all objects to be on the plane (2D scene). If i will change the third coord then they will be more far or more near to the eye or i am wrong ?

Comment: No, because the projection is ortographic.

Answer (score 1):

`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and you are good.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless your sprites have no transparency (i.e. they are only alpha-tested), giving them a Z value and enabling depth testing may not give you the results you want. Depth testing only prevents objects from appearing over previously-drawn objects that should be occluding them—it does not solve the general problem of order-independent transparency.

Comment: I understand what you mean @Pivot. However, from the look of the question, it looks like OP is rather new to OpenGL and therefore, first this answers is sufficient for him (you can tell by the "correct answer" he chose). First rule of teaching is to keep it simple for the beginners.